# sccm query cross apply outerapply doesnt give output

Tags: sql, left-join, cross-apply

iam running SQL query which has cross apply and outer apply , i need state names as complaint , non complaint and pending system restart, but data iam getting is for all assignment id , please find query

```
SELECT    cia.Assignment_UniqueID
        , cia.AssignmentID
        , cia.AssignmentName
        , cia.EnforcementDeadline
        , cia.StartTime
        , sn.StateName
        , NumberOfComputers = sc.StateCount
        , Tot.TotalClientPerAssignment
        , DeploymentStateID=sc.StateType*10000 + sc.StateID
        , PComputers = cast(sc.StateCount * 100.00 / isnull(NULLIF (Tot.TotalClientPerAssignment, 0), 1) AS decimal(5, 2))
FROM v_CIAssignment cia 
CROSS apply
    (SELECT  StateType, StateID, StateCount = count(*)
        FROM  v_AssignmentState_Combined
        WHERE AssignmentID = cia.AssignmentID AND StateType IN (300, 301)
        GROUP BY StateType, StateID) sc 
CROSS apply                                                          
    (SELECT DISTINCT TotalClientPerAssignment = count(atm.ResourceID) OVER (partition BY atm.assignmentid)
        FROM v_CIAssignmentTargetedMachines atm
        WHERE   atm.AssignmentID = cia.AssignmentID) Tot 
LEFT JOIN v_StateNames sn ON sn.TopicType = sc.StateType AND sn.StateID = sc.StateID
WHERE cia.AssignmentID = 2238
 -- and sn.statename like '%Compliant%' or sn.statename like '%Pending system restart%'
    and sn.statename like '%Compliant%' and  sn.statename like '%restart%'
ORDER BY cia.AssignmentID, sc.StateCount DESC, sn.StateName
```

output iam getting is as follows[image]

i need only statename as complaint , non complaint and pending restart for assignment id 2238 only but iam getting  data for all assignment id

can you please help

output of query

[image]

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your left join that's doesn't have any assignmentID

```
LEFT JOIN v_StateNames sn ON sn.TopicType = sc.StateType AND sn.StateID = sc.StateID
```

I suggest to use following query.

```
SELECT    cia.Assignment_UniqueID
        , cia.AssignmentID
        , cia.AssignmentName
        , cia.EnforcementDeadline
        , cia.StartTime
        , (SELECT StateName FROM v_StateNames WHERE TopicType = sc.StateType AND StateID = sc.StateID and statename like '%Compliant%' and  statename like '%restart%') as StateName
        , NumberOfComputers = sc.StateCount
        , Tot.TotalClientPerAssignment
        , DeploymentStateID=sc.StateType*10000 + sc.StateID
        , PComputers = cast(sc.StateCount * 100.00 / isnull(NULLIF (Tot.TotalClientPerAssignment, 0), 1) AS decimal(5, 2))
FROM v_CIAssignment cia 
CROSS apply
    (SELECT  StateType, StateID, StateCount = count(*)
        FROM  v_AssignmentState_Combined
        WHERE AssignmentID = cia.AssignmentID AND StateType IN (300, 301)
        GROUP BY StateType, StateID) sc 
CROSS apply                                                          
    (SELECT DISTINCT TotalClientPerAssignment = count(atm.ResourceID) OVER (partition BY atm.assignmentid)
        FROM v_CIAssignmentTargetedMachines atm
        WHERE   atm.AssignmentID = cia.AssignmentID) Tot 
WHERE cia.AssignmentID = 2238 
ORDER BY cia.AssignmentID, sc.StateCount DESC
```

Comment: its giving me statename as null, please find snapshot of output i need statename as 3 complaint non complaint and pending system restart